# Creating and naming a table in xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am trying to use `xlwings` to interface Excel from some of my Python code and unfortunately only found stackoverflow threads or documentation on accessing/reformatting *already existing* Excel tables rather than creating new ones from scratch.

edit: solution added based on David Zemen's answer (additional getters and setters for ListObject properties are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.displayname?view=vsto-2017).

```
import xlwings

df = ... # initialising some pandas DataFrame

book = xlwings.Book()
ws = book.sheets.active
ws.range("A1").options(index=False).value = df

# TODO: Create table
# downside: does not seem to be possible to define multiple tables
#           within a Sheet (based on explicit ranges)
tbl = ea_sheet.api.ListObjects.Add(1) 


# TODO: Set the name/formatting of the table
tbl.DisplayName = "tabname"  # sets the tablename
```

I know that I can expand the range selection using `ws.range("A1").expand('table')` and know that I can use the `.name` property of ranges to define them as named range.

However, does xlwings provide any means to create a table from a range (similar to using Home - Format as Table in the Excel UI)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if xlwings directly supports the creation of ListObjects, but since it exposes the [api](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.App.api), you could try something like:

```
xlSrcRange = 1
xlYes = 1
ws.range("A1").options(index=False).value = df
tbl_range = ws.range("A1").expand('table')
ws.api.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tbl_range, xlListObjectHasHeaders=xlYes)
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work and fails silently.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# creating a dummy dataframe
data = np.array(np.random.randint(0,100,(3,4)))
columns = ['A','B','A','C']
index = ['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3']
frame = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
book = xw.Book()
ws = book.sheets.active
ws.range("A1").options(index=False).value = frame
tbl_range = ws.range("A1").expand('table')
ws.api.ListObjects.Add(1, tbl_range)  ## This line fails, but no error is raised.
```

I suspect there is some problem passing the xlwings Range as the second parameter to the `Add` method.

I tried a few other things and if we omit the range argument, the `ws.api` call seems to work when I run it (with the caveat that the current ActiveCell/selection must be within the table area/used range):

```
ws.api.ListObjects.Add(1)
```

[image]

**Finally,** I was able to get it to work with the `ListObjects.Add` method but using the `.api` to pass a valid Excel range rather than an xlwings range:

```
ws.api.ListObjects.Add(1, ws.api.Range(tbl_range.address))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it seems to crash my IPyhon interpreter, but I will have to investigate what exactly is happening. Could you tell me if the api calls work for you?

Comment: yeah no. I just tested it from command line and the `ws.api` call just hangs for about several minutes and then crashes without raising any error.

Comment: @sim OK, see revised answer. It is working for me in python 3.7 from command line.

Comment: Zemes: Thanks a lot for your efforts! This indeed also works for me.

Comment: @sim I was able to get it to work with the `ListObjects.Add` method as well, updated answer w/ explanation of why (I think) it was failing previously. Cheers!

Comment: as of xlwings 0.21 (released Nov 9, 2020), there is native support for tables in xlwings. See https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.main.Tables.add